# what's the difference between switch_root and run_init?

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux, busybox

What's the difference between `switch_root` and `run_init`, besides `switch_root` being made by `busybox` while `run_init` is from `klibc`?

Thanks very much

Comment: Is there anything else you're wondering?

Answer (score 1):

They both perform exactly the same function, which is to switch to the "real" root and `execv(3)` the "real" `init(8)` program from an [initramfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs). They both assume that the filesystem that should become the root has been mounted on some directory, which they take as an argument.

(An initramfs is a (usually) temporary in-memory filesystem loaded by the bootloader. Its purpose is to do any setup that might be required before mounting the real root and switching to the real `init` program.)

Recent source code for `run-init` can be found [here](https://github.com/zenczykowski/klibc/blob/master/usr/kinit/run-init/runinitlib.c). `run_init()` is the entry point (called from *run-init.c*, which parses the arguments).

Recent source code for `switch_root` can be found [here](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/util-linux/switch_root.c). `switch_root_main()` is the entry point.

The code is short for both implementations (though a bit tricky), which makes it easy to compare them by eye. The only difference seems to be that they perform slightly different sanity checks, and that recent versions of `run-init` have an extra option to drop selected `capabilities(7)` before `execv()`'ing the new `init`.

Comment: Strangely, I found some old [patches](http://www.zytor.com/pipermail/klibc/2011-July/002980.html) that, among other things, rename `run_init` to `switch_root` in klibc. Not sure why they're not in [klibc-2.0.4](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/klibc/2.0/).